# Structure and fuction for picklist's values

Tags: apex, code

I'm tring to optimize the code below.

I'm looking for a structure where i can put the picklist's values and after (with just a condition) i want check the condition for all the values in the structure.

```
if ((lead.Status.trim()=='Archived' || lead.Status.trim()=='False'||lead.Status.trim()=='Lead - Never')
```

should be like this:

```
structure=['Archived','False','Lead - Never'];
if ((lead.Status.trim()==structure))
```

I can not find anything, do you know how i can do this?

Thanks in advantage for any advice.
Br

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `Set< String >`, you can use it's `contains()` method:

```
Set< String > structure = new Set< String >{'Archived', 'False', 'Lead - Never'};
if( structure.contains( lead.Status.trim() ) ){
.
. Your code here
.
}
```

Comment: Glad to help! :)